# Logging in Revit Design Automation add-in

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-designautomation

I want to send some diagnostic output to the default report.txt file.

In some posts it is shown that exceptions are logged to this report.txt file somehow (automatically or not?).

Also, I see in some samples that people do the logging with
`System.Console.WriteLine()`,

I've tried this, but still can't see it in the report file.

Could you tell me, how to achieve this?
I understand there is an option to create another log file and send it back with the result, but I think it would be easier to use this existing report.txt.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** System.Console.WriteLine() works.
The reason why I didn't see the output was that my add-in failed to load.
So, it simply didn't reach this line of code.

Answer (score 6):

Logging in Design Automation for Revit `appbundles` can indeed be done with `System.Console.WriteLine`. Anything sent to standard output will be capture in your `workitems` `report.txt`. For example.

The following code:

```
System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
```

Will generate the following lines in the `report.txt`:

```
[04/23/2020 19:20:59] Hello World!
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working in 2022. At least not for Revit 2021+

Comment: This is rather basic and has always worked. Could you provide a minimal reproducible case where this is broken. Please reach out to forge[dot]help[at]autodesk[dot]com.

Comment: I am trying to get information that automation plugin has reached execution method: public void Execute(DesignAutomationData data) - so I placend System.Console.WriteLine("Execution started!"); in there and when I download reporUrl from response there is no mention of it just standard logs about Initializing RevitCoreEngine and that it finished sucessfully.

Comment: At the end of report there is an error: Non-optional output [Output.rvt] is missing, which I assume is because of central model saving but all the logic happens before it and all logs should have been written by now and thus appear in log

Comment: I'd like more details to be able to help. The comments section here can't provide the right means to do so. Could you email to `forge[dot]help[at]autodesk[dot]com` and mention my name so it gets forwarded to me?

Comment: Eventually I found a problem in addin file I had <AddIn Type="Application"> instead of <AddIn Type="DBApplication">, now it shows the console logs. Thank you for being willing to help!

Comment: Glad to hear this is resolved!