# Forge Design Automation: FailedInstructions

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I am trying to start with tutorial. I think all the settings are in the right place, Revit version is matching, but for some reasons it keeps giving me this error for the workitems.

The full error report is as below. I found a similar question already posted on Stack Overflow, and the solution was not to use spaces in the file names, but I think that is not my case.

```
Defining appbundle and activity for Autodesk.Revit+2021
AppBundle: fOSxcRVEnAdnAzw6C0DRM1PmP72Hb3Pb.UpdateRVTParamAppBundle+dev, v6
Activity: Activity already defined
Uploading input file...
Workitem started: 4711da3fb2494245bd0da6c6eb6ed1c6
{
  "status": "failedInstructions",
  "reportUrl": "https://dasprod-store.s3.amazonaws.com/workItem/fOSxcRVEnAdnAzw6C0DRM1PmP72Hb3Pb/4711da3fb2494245bd0da6c6eb6ed1c6/report.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIATGVJZKM3NWBV4XNN&Expires=1636413657&x-amz-security-token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEBEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIQDR7EwSUbmdPQfabVhxZkVsCxme8LG%2FcNL296CwOXzIcAIgb2oO%2FrtQmlHeBJQWacXTqaF1Q5FKTr3QAcpX8L4fTWoqpAIIuv%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARADGgwyMjA0NzMxNTIzMTAiDKYmuAi%2Ftn5YnnJ1Iyr4AdoDI5z9S7ExLgJyDaLEesCRrbEvmzzS3DuMAUv0mUsC9gSsYVjDgmTXiDD77TGOTrzoFzZf6jKPiNpfU5trsXDYQIG2528Z2ejocz6eBgFx%2BGTGdPP91H9IY161LUGewUzBlH1SdXY5LTaNVvWKCCHt5CMnB8b7dhIrY1u%2FSasNZRX5iMxl5BBav%2Fis5NJ2h1mqGo2ZbTVkpMIX%2FgMasKztHUwqjGMgJTbQRKxJ8yOhc7MeZ4siq5xlRu2KE6No2miNfZOJDaelh6xf%2FOM80F1yO3kBc%2Bxr%2FeXzmrE4kJhufK7ZaJ7nBTNWrQnKH86%2FmtBsW9URXjjZMJbFo4wGOpoBX5ustqLM6CPLpQk7e0FLdDfbqCXIqgzGAFlgbq8%2BWFqpI4EIhGfh2PcR6NDFtKy4CfbOJsYZfSrqCVaVaAUYrxxB3k63anU%2FqZYPTdqFtODy%2FzNEi%2BXYO8y7L5wsuaZXOIMnYcTXAIwdgwS9QDpg8B2AfUiaGLxK7pcxIsDzatrJL3JjA6sfY93UMSCbleGrmyw2mhsrOKIzdQ%3D%3D&Signature=NoTMGDfXu6xzIYfzLbcmMQk4fM0%3D",
  "stats": {
    "timeQueued": "2021-11-08T09:50:56.5286545Z",
    "timeDownloadStarted": "2021-11-08T09:50:56.6226134Z",
    "timeInstructionsStarted": "2021-11-08T09:50:57.1190873Z",
    "timeInstructionsEnded": "2021-11-08T09:51:17.4083532Z",
    "bytesDownloaded": 5472285
  },
  "id": "4711da3fb2494245bd0da6c6eb6ed1c6"
}
[11/08/2021 09:50:56] Job information:
"CommandLine":[
  "$(engine.path)\\revitcoreconsole.exe /i \"$(args[inputFile].path)\" /al \"$(appbundles[UpdateRVTParamAppBundle].path)\""
]
"Settings":{
  "script": {
    "value": ""
  },
  "dasreportfaileduploadoptional": {
    "value": "true",
    "isEnvironmentVariable": true
  }
}
"Id":"4711da3fb2494245bd0da6c6eb6ed1c6"
"ActivityId":"fOSxcRVEnAdnAzw6C0DRM1PmP72Hb3Pb.UpdateRVTParamActivity+dev"
"Engine.Id":"Autodesk.Revit!75"
"Apps": [
"App.Id":"fOSxcRVEnAdnAzw6C0DRM1PmP72Hb3Pb.UpdateRVTParamAppBundle!6"
]
"BoundArguments":{
  "inputFile": {
    "localName": "$(inputFile)",
    "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/Masked:6QiT1FjL4plHl5biH1gJl7d5zWs=",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Masked:hNq+UMYxwlPcMBckXKxglITsBaQ="
    }
  },
  "inputJson": {
    "localName": "params.json",
    "url": "data:application/json, {'Width':'50','Height':'50'}"
  },
  "outputFile": {
    "localName": "outputFile.rvt",
    "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/Masked:140tqIHg3IIyBI/faMk4xc1SAo4=",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Masked:hNq+UMYxwlPcMBckXKxglITsBaQ="
    },
    "verb": "put"
  },
  "onComplete": {
    "ondemand": true,
    "optional": true,
    "url": "http://1784-193-111-52-227.ngrok.io/Masked:jy0CaBml28IlqYDgsUcHO2EnATg=",
    "verb": "post"
  },
  "onProgress": {
    "ondemand": true,
    "url": "https://wlnr5sjl3a.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Masked:UK/Z3b5X3xUWxXiH6C9r9i9UlRU=",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "x-das-authorize": "awssigv4(us-east-1)",
      "x-ads-token-data": "{\"access_token\":{\"client_id\":\"fOSxcRVEnAdnAzw6C0DRM1PmP72Hb3Pb\"},\"scope\":\"code:all\",\"expires_in\":3491,\"client_id\":\"fOSxcRVEnAdnAzw6C0DRM1PmP72Hb3Pb\"}",
      "x-ads-gateway-secret": "B8D93ECCBBCCEA74BD9EF64423B1C6FC"
    },
    "verb": "put"
  }
}
"Quotas":{
  "limitProcessingTimeSec": 10800,
  "limitTotalUncompressedAppsSizeInMB": 5000
}
[11/08/2021 09:50:56] Starting work item 4711da3fb2494245bd0da6c6eb6ed1c6
[11/08/2021 09:50:56] Start download phase.
[11/08/2021 09:50:56] Start downloading input: verb - 'GET', url - 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/fosxcrvenadnazw6c0drm1pmp72hb3pb-designautomation/objects/20211108105052_input_2021_revit_sample_file.rvt'
[11/08/2021 09:50:56] Embedded resource [ {'Width':'50','Height':'50'}] is saved as file: T:\Aces\Jobs\4711da3fb2494245bd0da6c6eb6ed1c6\params.json.
[11/08/2021 09:50:57] '5472256' bytes have been written to T:\Aces\Jobs\4711da3fb2494245bd0da6c6eb6ed1c6\20211108105052_input_2021_revit_sample_file.rvt.
[11/08/2021 09:50:57] End downloading file from 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/fosxcrvenadnazw6c0drm1pmp72hb3pb-designautomation/objects/20211108105052_input_2021_revit_sample_file.rvt'.
[11/08/2021 09:50:57] End download phase successfully.
[11/08/2021 09:50:57] Start preparing script and command line parameters.
[11/08/2021 09:50:57] Command line: [ /i "T:\Aces\Jobs\4711da3fb2494245bd0da6c6eb6ed1c6\20211108105052_input_2021_revit_sample_file.rvt" /al "T:\Aces\Applications\f9ca8965e8e9f19d85b2b143c733ef2e.fOSxcRVEnAdnAzw6C0DRM1PmP72Hb3Pb.UpdateRVTParamAppBundle[6].package"]
[11/08/2021 09:50:57] End preparing script and command line parameters.
[11/08/2021 09:50:57] Start script phase.
[11/08/2021 09:50:57] Start Revit Core Engine standard output dump.
[11/08/2021 09:50:57] Running in unattended mode.
[11/08/2021 09:50:57] ====== Revit is running: revitcoreconsole ======
[11/08/2021 09:50:57] Current Exe path: T:\Aces\AcesRoot\21.0\coreEngine\Exe\revitcoreconsole.exe
[11/08/2021 09:50:57] Echoing command line args:
[11/08/2021 09:50:57]   0:/i
[11/08/2021 09:50:57]   1:T:\Aces\Jobs\4711da3fb2494245bd0da6c6eb6ed1c6\20211108105052_input_2021_revit_sample_file.rvt
[11/08/2021 09:50:57]   2:/al
[11/08/2021 09:50:57]   3:T:\Aces\Applications\f9ca8965e8e9f19d85b2b143c733ef2e.fOSxcRVEnAdnAzw6C0DRM1PmP72Hb3Pb.UpdateRVTParamAppBundle[6].package
[11/08/2021 09:50:57]   4:/isolate
[11/08/2021 09:50:57]   5:HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\AppDataLow\Software\Autodesk\CoreUser\WorkItem_4711da3fb2494245bd0da6c6eb6ed1c6
[11/08/2021 09:50:57]   6:T:\Aces\Jobs\4711da3fb2494245bd0da6c6eb6ed1c6\userdata
[11/08/2021 09:50:57] Running RevitAssemblyResolver....
[11/08/2021 09:50:57] Initializing RevitCoreEngine...
[11/08/2021 09:50:57] Selected Revit\RCE install Path: (from app.config) C:\Revit2021
[11/08/2021 09:50:57] Resolving location of Revit/RevitCoreEngine installation...
[11/08/2021 09:50:57] Running user application....
[11/08/2021 09:51:01] Found an addIn for registration: Autodesk.Forge.Sample.DesignAutomation.Revit.addin
[11/08/2021 09:51:01] Initializing RCE....
[11/08/2021 09:51:01] Initializing RevitCoreEngine (and possibly running stub installer)...
[11/08/2021 09:51:01] Language not specified, using English-United States(ENU) as default.
[11/08/2021 09:51:04] Initialize and  get RCE: (VersionBuild) 21.1.30.74 (VersionNumber) 2021 (SubVersionNumber) 2021.2
[11/08/2021 09:51:16] RESULT: Failure - Result of running user app is failure
[11/08/2021 09:51:16] Finished running.  Process will return: TestError
[11/08/2021 09:51:16] ====== Revit finished running: revitcoreconsole ======
[11/08/2021 09:51:17] End Revit Core Engine standard output dump.
[11/08/2021 09:51:17] Error: Application revitcoreconsole.exe exits with code 4 which indicates an error.
[11/08/2021 09:51:17] End script phase.
[11/08/2021 09:51:17] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase CoreEngineExecution of job.
[11/08/2021 09:51:17] Job finished with result FailedExecution
[11/08/2021 09:51:17] Job Status:
{
  "status": "failedInstructions",
  "reportUrl": "https://dasprod-store.s3.amazonaws.com/workItem/fOSxcRVEnAdnAzw6C0DRM1PmP72Hb3Pb/4711da3fb2494245bd0da6c6eb6ed1c6/report.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIATGVJZKM3NWBV4XNN&Expires=1636413657&x-amz-security-token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEBEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIQDR7EwSUbmdPQfabVhxZkVsCxme8LG%2FcNL296CwOXzIcAIgb2oO%2FrtQmlHeBJQWacXTqaF1Q5FKTr3QAcpX8L4fTWoqpAIIuv%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARADGgwyMjA0NzMxNTIzMTAiDKYmuAi%2Ftn5YnnJ1Iyr4AdoDI5z9S7ExLgJyDaLEesCRrbEvmzzS3DuMAUv0mUsC9gSsYVjDgmTXiDD77TGOTrzoFzZf6jKPiNpfU5trsXDYQIG2528Z2ejocz6eBgFx%2BGTGdPP91H9IY161LUGewUzBlH1SdXY5LTaNVvWKCCHt5CMnB8b7dhIrY1u%2FSasNZRX5iMxl5BBav%2Fis5NJ2h1mqGo2ZbTVkpMIX%2FgMasKztHUwqjGMgJTbQRKxJ8yOhc7MeZ4siq5xlRu2KE6No2miNfZOJDaelh6xf%2FOM80F1yO3kBc%2Bxr%2FeXzmrE4kJhufK7ZaJ7nBTNWrQnKH86%2FmtBsW9URXjjZMJbFo4wGOpoBX5ustqLM6CPLpQk7e0FLdDfbqCXIqgzGAFlgbq8%2BWFqpI4EIhGfh2PcR6NDFtKy4CfbOJsYZfSrqCVaVaAUYrxxB3k63anU%2FqZYPTdqFtODy%2FzNEi%2BXYO8y7L5wsuaZXOIMnYcTXAIwdgwS9QDpg8B2AfUiaGLxK7pcxIsDzatrJL3JjA6sfY93UMSCbleGrmyw2mhsrOKIzdQ%3D%3D&Signature=NoTMGDfXu6xzIYfzLbcmMQk4fM0%3D",
  "stats": {
    "timeQueued": "2021-11-08T09:50:56.5286545Z",
    "timeDownloadStarted": "2021-11-08T09:50:56.6226134Z",
    "timeInstructionsStarted": "2021-11-08T09:50:57.1190873Z",
    "timeInstructionsEnded": "2021-11-08T09:51:17.4083532Z",
    "bytesDownloaded": 5472285
  },
  "id": "4711da3fb2494245bd0da6c6eb6ed1c6"
}
```

Comment: I cannot see more log on our side than what you have in the above log. I suspect something wrong in your Revit addin. Did you try running and debugging the addin with this tool(https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/design.automation-csharp-revit.local.debug.tool) via Desktop Revit first? Please try, it may reveal the addin's issue if any.

Comment: Yes, agree with Emma, this issue seems from your Revit plugin by checking the log, the input files are all downloaded successfully, need to debug to see what happened with the Revit plugin.

Comment: In addition to how to debug locally as posted in Emma's comment above, you can also log to console in your app bundle code and they will show up in your `report.txt`. See [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61395427/11057988)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Finally, as emma has said, I have tried locally with designautomationhandler with another addin and it has worked. My current problem is that I do not know how to continue to make the process work with asp.net. I have only seen this example https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/designautomation/appbundle/engines/revit.
I don't know if it is possible to contact someone who has done the process with design automation or some forge developer. I'm starting with this, thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @Zhong Wu, could you offer a further help for @ueser17356139?

Comment: @EmmaZhu, I will have a talk with him privately per the request...