# Need to extract family data from the Revit model using Design Automation API?

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-designautomation

There is a query regarding Design Automation API:

I have created a Revit plugin to extract Family data and it is also working fine with Revit Desktop application, But when I am executing it with the Design Automation API I am getting “failedInstructions”  response.

Here is the workitem id : 3e6eace60d1441ecba7ae74af3e6f89d.

Could you please help me to solve this problem to execute this plugin with design automation and return JSON data or CSV file.

```
Here is the Rest of the Job result:
Workitem started: 3e6eace60d1441ecba7ae74af3e6f89d                        
{
  "status": "failedInstructions",
  "reportUrl": "https://dasprod-store.s3.amazonaws.com/workItem/8wkyWTVWOZgRQPrphFGhxwvXSKGt2QAr/3e6eace60d1441ecba7ae74af3e6f89d/report.txt?X-Amz-Expires=48600&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEBoaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIC9CpfckcxAXhT4HdND132EKFO%2BEcKeZWurAXxTGW3b6AiEA%2FJRO3Hx%2B7yyOlr3mL7pzaEQhsKuG9L7XPl%2BdvMcsuqYqiQMIw%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARADGgwyMjA0NzMxNTIzMTAiDM4oP87c9jgFBnmk2irdAlPeXtCELl0R6YvZ2rES0gGdMgQEK9HHmiiPCeNMNkd09wudnRZZZRicZgO2GAdS6Fr4a2Ncu1DlhPSi3dTDolLXOtKmtyS46HmuLRDADhiPMSRJ1Pplq4CtkLcV5Zwb3Rdvfn9t4rFwqea8nGDON8Rgc%2Flf76CZYu2j0iLlNiDin0HhqSTnTYQs5qt0tHk9XdMR6XWBQIvJJWKK8ZHG%2FP4VeqpPJAgCdML2UbcxkZ%2FW7Z9Eb1QDm87hJmABcPGwhDsysiLBms%2FDiU5XK0%2B4eUQ2HnVjYeKLGQ0%2B85IhY44i%2FAwKKqdturvwSscCrZcVYwqDfbTvPehjJByWN621fHnb0SKnC5Z5IlSyyj70KjDhf6pFdjIk9%2F9jFOrKqWvVm1CD8PVvDPCpOPFAc1Q9XH01vaRnFEwHYgPNf6DMABuCsFiiGkQDdYqSTK44%2Fe0KDHD6xV2tUU8itQhk4EgwsczUpgY6ngHQxDU7D5dkdkql5gFhw65T%2B7z1IygHk2%2FEUAucH8PGIXmhnHUzQTsIStE%2FLC%2Fou5FRGIAzVmpBn9KAc%2Fa2h6NF1T6HhBWhxCjnsD3UgGnErLEXXrWyxH74%2FDqMJ4XQUkSAynak%2B7hZGxrm1nhTpGohoFXqozpAbE5VHHwJl%2BJCw4hAeNFvQHEEhvTCZPqyLZMjFJ0z%2BzcGFQhxKQI5cQ%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIATGVJZKM3LKNHYI47/20230810/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20230810T181326Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=95cadf6a11e438166f5c28d008c30b18dbbdad88ccbdb47b9cd4c0f615c4462f",
  "stats": {
    "timeQueued": "2023-08-10T18:13:26.7574216Z",
    "timeDownloadStarted": "2023-08-10T18:13:26.9379036Z",
    "timeInstructionsStarted": "2023-08-10T18:13:27.5452591Z",
    "timeInstructionsEnded": "2023-08-10T18:13:51.6618916Z",
    "bytesDownloaded": 13680640
  },
  "id": "3e6eace60d1441ecba7ae74af3e6f89d"
}
[08/10/2023 18:13:26] Job information:
{
  "CommandLine": [
    "$(engine.path)\\revitcoreconsole.exe /i \"$(args[inputFile].path)\" /al \"$(appbundles[ExportDataAppBundle].path)\""
  ],
  "Settings": {
    "script": {
      "value": ""
    },
    "dasOpenNetwork": {
      "value": "true",
      "isEnvironmentVariable": true
    }
  },
  "Id": "3e6eace60d1441ecba7ae74af3e6f89d",
  "ActivityId": "8wkyWTVWOZgRQPrphFGhxwvXSKGt2QAr.ExportDataActivity+dev",
  "EngineId": "Autodesk.Revit_2022!111",
  "Apps": [
    "8wkyWTVWOZgRQPrphFGhxwvXSKGt2QAr.ExportDataAppBundle!1"
  ],
  "BoundArguments": {
    "inputFile": {
      "localName": "$(inputFile)",
      "url": "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:8wkywtvwozgrqprphfghxwvxskgt2qar-designautomation/20230810114245_input_58FloorNoOpeningsNoOSB.rvt",
      "headers": {
        "Authorization": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjY0RE9XMnJoOE9tbjNpdk1NU0xlNGQ2VHEwUSIsInBpLmF0bSI6Ijd6M2gifQ.eyJzY29wZSI6WyJidWNrZXQ6Y3JlYXRlIiwiYnVja2V0OnJlYWQiLCJidWNrZXQ6ZGVsZXRlIiwiZGF0YTpyZWFkIiwiZGF0YTp3cml0ZSIsImRhdGE6Y3JlYXRlIiwiY29kZTphbGwiXSwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoiOHdreVdUVldPWmdSUVBycGhGR2h4d3ZYU0tHdDJRQXIiLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2F1dG9kZXNrLmNvbS9hdWQvYWp3dGV4cDYwIiwianRpIjoiMDVhM0NKWVRScXA5VUYyWjA5YU55SnNoV3pSdEdabmk3b3lPYkUzT3M2RlFSNUlLN1dCaDU5a1pLOG8wUHk5aCIsImV4cCI6MTY5MTY5NDYxN30.qMYGQomGqMwgzbQWxSODi97zdEYuDjEf_R6WuNupcWYmbioYRBXOBRjknUSX4PrhLFuqZoDPg9YZpb8APFQpfhyHy88mML04Mqt1LP2KJkeKJY1ZrWlQvXZWqMRljw6m3Q-L8PVwa3MKkOJ3Vgfifq1EB_vbEBjWkbig2ROkh1uLOSQ1KTX_HaJsMMqkQ-y17TUfgCD4onWiqcnSOzWux1DTgRdjz0pcu5W2w1B0SF5IDkCQEHUMFHyNRRWTv6-XGMdSgPEH2EHopXbiFyGSc94JX8dkjGn9l-pSUl2Rx8QS6D4W-16JvwsYD9Yj74A4fY7kChtGHP9UuJ1AH2DTpQ"
      }
    },
    "outputFile": {
      "localName": "outputFile.rvt",
      "url": "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:8wkywtvwozgrqprphfghxwvxskgt2qar-designautomation/20230810114305_output_58FloorNoOpeningsNoOSB.rvt",
      "headers": {
        "Authorization": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjY0RE9XMnJoOE9tbjNpdk1NU0xlNGQ2VHEwUSIsInBpLmF0bSI6Ijd6M2gifQ.eyJzY29wZSI6WyJidWNrZXQ6Y3JlYXRlIiwiYnVja2V0OnJlYWQiLCJidWNrZXQ6ZGVsZXRlIiwiZGF0YTpyZWFkIiwiZGF0YTp3cml0ZSIsImRhdGE6Y3JlYXRlIiwiY29kZTphbGwiXSwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoiOHdreVdUVldPWmdSUVBycGhGR2h4d3ZYU0tHdDJRQXIiLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2F1dG9kZXNrLmNvbS9hdWQvYWp3dGV4cDYwIiwianRpIjoiMDVhM0NKWVRScXA5VUYyWjA5YU55SnNoV3pSdEdabmk3b3lPYkUzT3M2RlFSNUlLN1dCaDU5a1pLOG8wUHk5aCIsImV4cCI6MTY5MTY5NDYxN30.qMYGQomGqMwgzbQWxSODi97zdEYuDjEf_R6WuNupcWYmbioYRBXOBRjknUSX4PrhLFuqZoDPg9YZpb8APFQpfhyHy88mML04Mqt1LP2KJkeKJY1ZrWlQvXZWqMRljw6m3Q-L8PVwa3MKkOJ3Vgfifq1EB_vbEBjWkbig2ROkh1uLOSQ1KTX_HaJsMMqkQ-y17TUfgCD4onWiqcnSOzWux1DTgRdjz0pcu5W2w1B0SF5IDkCQEHUMFHyNRRWTv6-XGMdSgPEH2EHopXbiFyGSc94JX8dkjGn9l-pSUl2Rx8QS6D4W-16JvwsYD9Yj74A4fY7kChtGHP9UuJ1AH2DTpQ"
      },
      "verb": "put"
    },
    "onComplete": {
      "ondemand": true,
      "optional": true,
      "url": "https://e02d-14-99-194-2.ngrok.io/api/aps/callback/designautomation?id=4urhMPwc_rcm3c5P47eFcw&outputFileName=20230810114305_output_58FloorNoOpeningsNoOSB.rvt",
      "verb": "post"
    }
  },
  "Quotas": {
    "limitProcessingTimeSec": 10800,
    "limitTotalUncompressedAppsSizeInMB": 5000
  }
}
[08/10/2023 18:13:27] Starting work item 3e6eace60d1441ecba7ae74af3e6f89d
[08/10/2023 18:13:27] Start download phase.
[08/10/2023 18:13:27] Start downloading input: verb - 'GET', url - 'urn:adsk.objects:os.object:8wkywtvwozgrqprphfghxwvxskgt2qar-designautomation/20230810114245_input_58FloorNoOpeningsNoOSB.rvt'
[08/10/2023 18:13:27] End downloading file. Source=urn:adsk.objects:os.object:8wkywtvwozgrqprphfghxwvxskgt2qar-designautomation/20230810114245_input_58FloorNoOpeningsNoOSB.rvt,LocalFile=T:\Aces\Jobs\3e6eace60d1441ecba7ae74af3e6f89d\20230810114245_input_58FloorNoOpeningsNoOSB.rvt,BytesDownloaded=13680640,Duration=386ms
[08/10/2023 18:13:27] End download phase successfully.
[08/10/2023 18:13:27] Start preparing script and command line parameters.
[08/10/2023 18:13:27] Command line: [ /i "T:\Aces\Jobs\3e6eace60d1441ecba7ae74af3e6f89d\20230810114245_input_58FloorNoOpeningsNoOSB.rvt" /al "T:\Aces\Applications\03fdf20cfa0ae454a88e395019445244.8wkyWTVWOZgRQPrphFGhxwvXSKGt2QAr.ExportDataAppBundle[1].package"]
[08/10/2023 18:13:27] End preparing script and command line parameters.
[08/10/2023 18:13:27] Start script phase.
[08/10/2023 18:13:27] Start Revit Core Engine standard output dump.
[08/10/2023 18:13:28] ====== Revit is running: revitcoreconsole ======
[08/10/2023 18:13:28] Current Exe path: T:\Aces\AcesRoot\22.0\coreEngine\Exe\revitcoreconsole.exe
[08/10/2023 18:13:28] Echoing command line args:
[08/10/2023 18:13:28]   0:/i
[08/10/2023 18:13:28]   1:T:\Aces\Jobs\3e6eace60d1441ecba7ae74af3e6f89d\20230810114245_input_58FloorNoOpeningsNoOSB.rvt
[08/10/2023 18:13:28]   2:/al
[08/10/2023 18:13:28]   3:T:\Aces\Applications\03fdf20cfa0ae454a88e395019445244.8wkyWTVWOZgRQPrphFGhxwvXSKGt2QAr.ExportDataAppBundle[1].package
[08/10/2023 18:13:28]   4:/isolate
[08/10/2023 18:13:28]   5:HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\AppDataLow\Software\Autodesk\CoreUser\WorkItem_3e6eace60d1441ecba7ae74af3e6f89d
[08/10/2023 18:13:28]   6:T:\Aces\Jobs\3e6eace60d1441ecba7ae74af3e6f89d\userdata
[08/10/2023 18:13:28] Selected Revit\RCE install Path: (from app.config)
[08/10/2023 18:13:28] Resolving location of Revit/RevitCoreEngine installation...
[08/10/2023 18:13:28] Loading RCE ....
[08/10/2023 18:13:32] Running user application....
[08/10/2023 18:13:32] Found an addIn for registration: ExportData.addin
[08/10/2023 18:13:32] Language not specified, using English-United States(ENU) as default.
[08/10/2023 18:13:36] Get RCE: (VersionBuild) 22.1.50.7 (VersionNumber) 2022 (SubVersionNumber) 2022.1.5
[08/10/2023 18:13:50] RESULT: Failure - Result of running user app is failure
[08/10/2023 18:13:50] Finished running.  Process will return: TestError
[08/10/2023 18:13:50] ====== Revit finished running: revitcoreconsole ======
[08/10/2023 18:13:51] End Revit Core Engine standard output dump.
[08/10/2023 18:13:51] Error: Application revitcoreconsole.exe exits with code 4 which indicates an error.
[08/10/2023 18:13:51] End script phase.
[08/10/2023 18:13:51] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase CoreEngineExecution of job.
[08/10/2023 18:13:52] Job finished with result FailedExecution
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [08/10/2023 18:13:50] RESULT: Failure - Result of running user app is failure
> [08/10/2023 18:13:50] Finished running.  Process will return: TestError

These lines in the log file indicate some error in your `AppBundle` code. You will have to share that code for someone be able to point out what it might be.

Before you do that, you might consider [local debugging](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/design-automation-debug-revit-plugin-locally) and/or [logging verbose comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61395427/11057988) in your AppBundle so you can diagnose the problem yourselves.

Comment: Thanks @Rahul I have executed the local debugging and fix the error.

Comment: Can you also tell me if possible that how can we write the data from revit plugin to database using Design Automation API for Revit?

Comment: What data base is this? Any `https` calls should work, from your DA addin.

Comment: I have a MySQL database.

Comment: Is there any way to get the list of data in return from the design automation api?

Comment: What data are you looking to get from Design Automation? Design Automation by itself is agnostic of data you are operating on.

Comment: So I have created a plugin that stores family data in a list from the given Revit model.
Initially I was extracting the data from the log of the Workitem on it's success response, but the data has become very large and the console is not able to write all the data.
So if you know any way to get that data from the plugin, that will be extremely helpful?

Comment: Have you tried to add an output parameter/argument to activity/workitem?

Comment: I tried it but I but always get failed instruction as response. I am having trouble in adding the path for the  output file in the plugin.

Comment: What is the path you are saving the file? Could you post a separate question? I can answer there. Comments section do not allow much formatting.

Comment: Sure, I will post the above comment as a question.